# Can I use a list comprehension to get a sequential position of each non-blank line when reading in a file?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have been struggling how to create a list of tuples that have the line number and the line but I want to enumerate only non-blank lines

This gets me exactly what I want

```
counter = 0
line_list = []
for line in open(file).readlines()
    if line.strip() == '':
        continue
    line_list.append((counter,line.strip()))
    counter +=1
```

when I do this

```
line_list = [(index,line) for index, line in \
             enumerate(open(file).readlines() if line.strip() != 0]
```

as expected (after I thought about it) index advances for each line as it is read in so I get gaps in the numbers for every blank line read in

I also tried

```
counter = 0
line_list = [(counter,line) for line in open(file).readlines() \
            if line.strip != '' counter +=1]
```

this gives me a syntax error

Here is an example of the type of raw file

```
'Some words are in a line \n'
' maybe another line with more words\n'
'\n'
'\n'
'See the one or more blank lines\n'
'maybe more or less word\n'
'\n'
'\n'
'lots of lines with text\n'
```

Comment: So should the line that contains `See the one or more blank lines` be numbered as the 5th line or 3rd?

Comment: @F.J. should it be two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enumerate just the non-empty lines:

```
[(index, line) for index,line in enumerate(l for l in open(file) if l.strip())]
```

Comment: That's just because you wanted a comprehension (as per your question title). You can just skip it and do as @F.J suggests. Or better, if you don't need the whole list, apply the `enumerate` to a for loop...

Answer (score 2):

```
line_list = list(enumerate(line for line in open(file) if line.strip()))
```

Comment: Thanks I learned something here @Ricardo Cardenes gets the answer points because he was first and it worked but this was very helpful

Comment: Yeah pretty much the same approach, just removed an unnecessary list comprehension.